# What's a better way to remove a sub folder that attached in the file path in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
   string EV_HOME = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EV_HOME");
   string myFilePath = EV_HOME + "\\MyFolder\\MySubFolder";
```

Suppose `EV_HOME` return **C:\myprogram\leanrning\anotherfolder**

How can I remove the folder `anotherfolder` and get `myFilePath` as this

**C:\myprogram\leanrning\MyFolder\MySubFolder**

What I know is loop the Ev_HOME value and build each one (except the last one) as a new string.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string EV_HOME = @"C:\myprogram\leanrning\anotherfolder\";
            string parentFolder = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(EV_HOME).Parent.FullName;
            string myFilePath = parentFolder + "\\MyFolder\\MySubFolder";
            Console.WriteLine(myFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong on many levels. 1) Never hard-code paths to system directories (even in environment variables). 2) Do not concatenate paths yourself or assume what the directory separator is. Use the [`Path.Combine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) designed explicitly for this purpose.